# Como proceder para implementar uma PreparedStatement no Android?

Tags: java, android, jdbc, revisão-de-código

Estamos utilizando o [SQLDroid](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid) para funcionar como driver JDBC para o Android. Porém, o SQLDroid é um envólucro para as chamadas da API do Android, e essa API [não lida bem com nulos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15952937/4438007).

Assim, para usarmos `PreparedStatements` diretamente necessitamos contornar todos os `setNull()` (ou algum `setString(idx, null)` que possa ocorrer indiretamente, como quando a variável está nula), a primeira estratégia foi fazer essa verificação enquanto se monta a *query*. Por exemplo, fizemos o seguinte contorno para a busca de produto dado um parâmetro textual (e que ocasionalmente pode ser nulo se chamado programaticamente):

```java
// String param é um parâmetro
String paramStr = Optional.ofNullable(param).orElse("");
String paramOrNullStr = Optional.ofNullable(param).map(p -> "'" + p + "'").orElse("null");

String query =  " SELECT " + 
                "   p.cd_produto, " + 
                "   ov.cd_cliente, " + 
                "   ov.cd_org_venda, " + 
                "   ov.cd_tab_preco " + 
                " FROM produto p " + 
                " CROSS JOIN org_venda ov " + 
                " WHERE " + 
                "   ( " + paramOrNullStr + " IS NULL) OR " + 
                "   ( " + 
                "       p.nm_produto LIKE '%" + paramStr + "%' OR " + 
                "       p.cd_produto LIKE '%" + paramStr + "%' OR " + 
                "       p.cd_referencia LIKE '%" + paramStr + "%' OR " + 
                "       p.cod_barras LIKE '%" + paramStr + "%' " +
                "    ) ";
```

Porém isso é algo contraintuitivo e contraproducente. Assim, comecei a trabalhar em implementar um contorno para isso. Como o Android oferece as interfaces do JDBC, abri um projeto qualquer em Java 8 e criei uma classe para estender de `PreparedStatement`. O Eclipse criou para mim a classe com uma enorme lista de `TODOs` e, quando confirmei o funcionamento e pus para compilar no projeto Android, me deparo com isso:

```
C:\Users\Jefferson Quesado\Documents\geosales-nu\numobile\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\evo_mobile\sqldroid\drive\PstmtNullSafe.java:358: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

    @Override

    ^

C:\Users\Jefferson Quesado\Documents\geosales-nu\numobile\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\evo_mobile\sqldroid\drive\PstmtNullSafe.java:360: error: invalid method reference

        putPreparer("closeOnCompletion", PreparedStatement::closeOnCompletion);

                                         ^

  cannot find symbol

    symbol:   method closeOnCompletion()

    location: interface PreparedStatement
```

Quando fui ver, essa função [surgiu no Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#closeOnCompletion--), junto da `isCloseOnCompletion`, mas não entrou no Android (veja a definição da [`Statement`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Statement.html))

Então, como fazer a compatibilidade da minha classe que implementa `PreparedStatement` de maneira adequado, de modo que funcione no Android?

- devo me preocupar apenas com o Android e remover esses métodos?,
- devo transformar em um proxy e fazer os direcionamentos de acordo com os métodos chamados?,
- ou devo simplesmente remover a anotação de `@Override` e deixar um retorno falso? (como o [SQLDroid fez](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid/blob/1.0.3/src/main/java/org/sqldroid/SQLDroidPreparedStatement.java#L940-L949))

Quais fatores devo levar para a decisão da estratégia desejada?

Comment: Não sei a resposta (se soubesse, eu postaria uma). No entanto, qualquer que seja ela, essa injeção de SQL que você deixou aberta seria uma coisa muito ruim.

Comment: Já ouviu falar do lombok? Se não, talvez isso te ajude: https://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html

Comment: @VictorStafusa, já ouvi falar muito tempo atrás para simplificar getters e setters. Vou dar uma lida no assunto, obrigado pela dica

Comment: De fato, isso ajuda muito quando se tem muitos _delegates_ porém poucos realmente necessários `@Override`. Como eu vou criar o `PreparedStatement` real de modo _lazy_ para poder substituir as marcas de parâmetro `?` pela string `null` no SQL, eu estava tentando manter essas chamadas de preparar a statement no momento devido. Mas, de fato, essa alternativa do Lombok é uma maneira rápida para interceptar algumas chamadas e delegar as outras